# filtering array of array objects in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have written a property in angular 4 application which returns an array of arrays. I need to filter one element out of one array in that set. When I try and apply the filter the rest of the arrays get omitted. I believe its due to the way i have applied the filter. Its only returning me assumptions object. Could someone correct me where I am going wrong. In the example below assumptionsInput is an array  object that contains several objects within itself.

For Example it contains

```
assumptions
currentCaptiveBalanceSheets
minimumCaptitalContributions
specialAccountingRules
```

The AssumptionsInput interface

```
 export interface AssumptionsInput  {

        assumptions: ModelingAssumption[];
        specialAccountRules: ModelingAssumption[];
        minimumCapitalContributions: ModelingAssumption[];
        currentCaptiveBalanceSheets: ModelingAssumption[];
    }


 export interface ModelingAssumption  {

        fieldInfo: FieldInfo;
        value: FieldValue;
    }
```

I need to be able to return all the array object above except filter one element within assumptions called fyDate.

**Original code**

```
get assumptionsInput() {
    return this._assumptionsService.run.assumptionsInput;
  }
```

**Modified Code**

```
get assumptionsInput() {
    return this._assumptionsService.run.assumptionsInput.assumptions.filter(x=> x.fieldInfo.key === 'fyDate');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter assumptionsInput, must be like

```
assumptionsInput.filter(x=>x.assumptions.fieldInfo.key=='fyDate')
```

If you want to show all the assumptionsInput, but in assumptions only thats values with a condition

```
let filteredAssumptions=assumptionsInput.map((a)=>{
   return {
       ...a,
       assumptions:a.assumptions.filter(a=>a.fieldInfor.key=='fyDate'
   }
})
```